# .htaccess : Redirect all http requests to one file whitout 404 resp. code

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, url-rewriting

I want to redirect all http request to one file `controller.php`

```
# My .htaccess
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  !\.(.+)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)([^/])$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1$2/ [L,R=301]
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$      controller.php
```

Consider this request `http://mysite.com/en-US/messages/new/` 
I have php script to get all url parameters and treat them
`controller.php` is been displayed but a 404 response code is sent too by Apache. 
**How can I make a good rewrite rule to prevent 404 response ?**

Comment: I guess you should check [this](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/custom-error.html) link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You regex doesn't include `/` characters.

```
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-/]+)$      controller.php
```